# Combining 2 tables with the same structure but stored in different databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I think I'm looking for a command called "INSERT BUT IGNORE MY INCORRECT KEYS INTO" command...

I have a table on my local machine which looks like this. id is auto-incremented:-

```
id name
1  bob
2  phil
```

and another on my server which looks like this:-

```
id name
1  jane
2  sally
```

and I want to insert the records from one into the other so I end up with a table with records 1,2,3,4.

If I take the export option in my local phpmyadmin (although I'm not fussy about admin tools) I get this sql:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'),(2, 'Phil')
```

But I can't run this on the server because of the duplicate keys. I realise I could just edit the sql with a bit of regex, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the databases, you can add a value to all of the primary key fields, then there will be no collisions when inserting.  Just be sure that you add the same value to every affected table (if you are combining more than one), and every foreign key field referenced by any tables.

Disclaimer: The following will affect all rows. Don't execute it until you are certain you want to.

```
-- Add 5000 to all ids
UPDATE tbl SET id = id + 5000;
```

You'll then be able export and to combine the tables by `INSERT` without collisions. Your export output will look like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (5001, 'Bob'),(5002, 'Phil')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much for an answer I should have been clever enough to figure out:-)

Comment: perhaps an addition to this would be to replace the 5000 value with the max(id) value from the server target table? Furthermore, once the insert has been executed into the server target table run an alter table statement to set the auto_increment value (assuming there is one!) to the new max value + 1 of the server target table? This will prevent subsequent inserts into the server target table from failing with a duplicate primary violation.